# Class attributes with a "calculated" name

Tags: python, exec, class-attributes

When defining class attributes through "calculated" names, as in:

```
class C(object):
    for name in (....):
        exec("%s = ..." % (name,...))
```

is there a different way of handling the numerous attribute definitions than by using an exec?  getattr(C, name) does not work because C is not defined, during class construction...

Comment: BTW: your tag of "compile-time" is jarring on a Python question.  Compilation isn't really an important consideration here.  This is about defining a class, not code compilation, which is an orthogonal issue.

Comment: @Ned: You're right.  I used the tag "compile-time" because the code in the example is only executed at compile time.  Technically, it could be executed lazily, and the need for defining the class would still remain.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

How about:

```
class C(object):
    blah blah

for name in (...):
    setattr(C, name, "....")
```

That is, do the attribute setting after the definition.

Answer (score 3):

```
class C (object):
    pass

c = C()
c.__dict__['foo'] = 42
c.foo # returns 42
```

Answer (score 2):

If your entire class is "calculated", then may I suggest the `type` callable. This is especially useful if your original container was a dict:

```
d = dict(('member-%d' % k, k*100) for k in range(10))
C = type('C', (), d)
```

This would give you the same results as

```
class C(object):
    member-0 = 0
    member-1 = 100
    ...
```

If your needs are really complex, consider metaclasses. (In fact, `type` *is* a metaclass =)

Comment: This results in attribute-names that cannot be accessed using normal Python syntax, because identifiers cannot contain the hyphen-minus character.  It would be better to use `_` in this example.

Answer (score 0):

What about using metaclasses for this purpose?

Check out [Question 100003 : What is a metaclass in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-is-a-metaclass-in-python).